# Gradle : Cannot initialize variables using shell commands

Tags: shell, variables, gradle, build.gradle

I want to initialize a few variables via some shell commands in my `build.gradle` file

```
def YEAR_MONTH_DAY=['date +%F'].execute().text.trim()
def BUILD_DATE=['date -u +%FT%T.%3NZ)'].execute().text.trim()
def IMAGE_NAME ='bca/cab-imaging'
def SHORT_VCS_REF=['git rev-parse --short HEAD'].execute().text.trim()
def VERSION=YEAR_MONTH_DAY+'-'+SHORT_VCS_REF
```

but i get

```
> Cannot run program "date +%F": error=2, No such file or directory
```

what am i doing wrong? How do i initialize my variables via shell commands?

I also tried

```
def YEAR_MONTH_DAY= new ByteArrayOutputStream()
exec{
    commandLine "sh","date +%F"
    standardOutput = YEAR_MONTH_DAY;
}
```

but i got

`> Process 'command 'sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127`

Answer (score 0):

here's how i did it

```
project.ext.IMAGE_NAME='bca/cab-imaging'
project.ext.BUILD_DATE= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
project.ext.YEAR_MONTH_DAY=new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
project.ext.SHORT_VCS_REF=new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec{
        commandLine 'git','rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = SHORT_VCS_REF;
    }
project.ext.VERSION=project.YEAR_MONTH_DAY+"-"+"$SHORT_VCS_REF"
```

then i can just access them as `project.VERSION` etc.